# How can I use this Code as Snippet for JS in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sublimetext3, code-snippets

When I am trying to use, the dollar signs are preventing the code snippet to work properly...

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {    
    var $if = $(e.delegateTarget).find('iframe');
    var src = $if.attr("src");
    $if.attr("src", '/empty.html');
    $if.attr("src", src);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the Dollar Sign (`$`) with Back Slash (`\`) while creating the new snippet with sublime text. Your snippet content should be as : `<content>`

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
\$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {    
    var \$if = \$(e.delegateTarget).find('iframe');
    var src = \$if.attr("src");
    \$if.attr("src", '/empty.html');
    \$if.attr("src", src);
});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>myscript</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```